# MeteorJS Styling is sometimes working?

Tags: css, meteor

I am currently working on a online resume website, and I am experiencing an odd issue with meteor.

CSS styling for certain elements on the page will work, and not work at the same time. What I mean is say you load the site and land on skillset you will see a white background behind the text and grey words. Now if you navigate to another page and come back all you will see are the stars and H2 tags the background has become transparent. However if you open your Developer console the background will magically come back.

Now example 2, with the Developer console already open repeat the process above. Open Skillset, navigate away, and go back to skillset. Now you will see the CSS styling is there, mess with the background for the class '.skillset' and you will see that the background is back. Isnt this odd?

My site is http://patrickml.com/

Comment: i can't reproduce your error. The site looks good to me.

Comment: Can't reproduce either, LGTM.

Comment: Add I have been able to replicate it on many devices

this is what I am seeing

http://cl.ly/image/0L0e2k3t0u16

1. load the site http://patrickml.com/
2. Go to skillset
3. Click on work history
4. Go back to skillset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I needed to add "position: relative" to my main container. I do not understand why, but it did fix my issue.